# What is wrong is this code, I am trying to print port value but it shows an error

Tags: node.js

Trying to get port value. Which is already declared.

```
app.listen(port,() => console.log('Server started on port:'${port}''));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to back-tick character

```
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port:${port}`));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 0):

You are using quotes instead of back tick. You can use `${variables}` only in javascript templating for which the strings are enclosed in backticks. The following code will fix your issue

```
app.listen(port,() => console.log(`Server started on port:${port}`));
```